# How to run security check on Angular project or how to run OWASP dependency check for Angular Project

Tags: angular, security, owasp

Not getting exact procedure to run OWASP dependency check for angular project, It will be helpful if any one would suggest step by step procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps to Install and run OWASP Dependency Check in Angular Project:

1. Install OWASP dependency check in angular project using below command

   ```
        "npm install owasp-dependency-check"
   ```
2. Add below script in package.json

   ```
         "scripts": {
           ...
           "owasp": "owasp-dependency-check --project \"YOUR PROJECT 
           NAME\" [options]"
          }
   ```
3. Example of script

   ```
   "owasp-dependency-check --project \"YOUR PROJECT NAME\" --exclude=dependency-check-bin --exclude=node_moduels --out=dependency-check-reports -f HTML"
   ```
4. Then run below command to generate report

   ```
   "npm run owasp"
   ```
5. It will take some time to generate HTML file under dependency-check-reports. Once report is generated open the HTML file and check the vulnerabilities.